# How to prove $\mu^\ast(A)=\mu(A)$ for every elementary set A?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

How to prove $\mu^\ast(A)=\mu(A)$ for every elementary set A? ( $\mu^\ast(A)$ is the outer measure of $A$)

I'm doing Lebesgue Theory chapter of Baby Rudin and I don't understand the underlined part in the picture.

Do we have $\mu^\ast(A)\le\mu^\ast(G)\le\mu(G)$?

[image]

Definitions:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: $\mu^{\star}(A)=\inf\{\mu(G):A\subseteq G\text{ and }G\text{ is an open elementary set}\}$ (?)

Comment: His definition seems to be a little different, there's a countable sum.@DanielCalderón

Comment: The definition of $\mu^*(A)$ is the inf of $\mu(B)$ over all open $B$ such that $A\subset B.$ So if $A\subset G$ and $G$ is open then $\mu^*(A)\leq \mu (G).$... BTW I haven't seen the term "elementary set" anywhere else. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is:

$$\mu^*(A) = \inf \left\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n): (A_n)_{n=1}^\infty \text{ are open elementary sets such that } A \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right\}$$

We assumed that $G$ is an open elementary set such that $A \subseteq G$. Define a sequence of open elementary sets $(G_n)_{n=1}^\infty = (G, \emptyset, \emptyset, \emptyset, \ldots)$.

We have $A \subseteq G = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty G_n$ so by definition of $\mu^*(A)$, we have $$\mu^*(A) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(G_n) = \mu(G) + \mu(\emptyset) + \mu(\emptyset) + \ldots = \mu(G)$$

Notice that this really means that the infimum goes over all finite or countable coverings of $A$ by elementary sets.

$$\mu^*(A) = \inf \left\{\sum_{i\in I} \mu(A_i): \{A_i\}_{i\in I} \text{ are open elementary sets such that } A \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i \text{ and } I \subseteq \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

---

This implies that $\mu^*(A) \le \mu(G) \le \mu(A) + \varepsilon$. So, for arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $\mu^*(A) \le \mu(A) + \varepsilon$ therefore we can conclude $\mu^*(A) \le \mu(A)$.

Comment: Why can  $\mu^*(A) \le \mu(A) + \varepsilon, \varepsilon > 0$ lead to $\mu^*(A) \le \mu(A)$?

Comment: @Hank Assume $\mu^*(A) \le \mu(A) + \varepsilon, \forall\varepsilon > 0
$ but $\mu^*(A) > \mu(A)$. Then $\frac12(\mu^*(A) - \mu(A)) > 0$, so
$$\mu^*(A) \le \mu(A) + \frac12(\mu^*(A) - \mu(A)) = \frac12(\mu^*(A) + \mu(A))$$
Rearranging gives $$\mu^*(A) \le \mu(A)$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Fantastic proof! Thanks a lot!